# get props passed to component inside getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13, getserversideprops

In Next.js, let's assume we have this component:

```
<MyComponent width=150 />
```

Inside this component, I know how to fetch data inside getServerSideProps

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    const data = await fetchData() as DataInterface;
    
    return { props: { data: data } }
}
```

Inside the main function of the component, I also know how to get access to the fetched data props.

```
export default function MyComponent( {data}: InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>) { etc...
```

Now, in the context of this component, how can I also access the "width" prop passed to the MyComponent component?

Thanks

Comment: Not a full answer: `getServerSideProps` is only valid for page components ([docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#when-does-getserversideprops-run) which cannot take props. The function cannot be used on single components. The app router provides functionality to load component specific data on the server using react server components though and should ideally be used moving forward instead of the pages router you are using.

Comment: Thanks @geisterfurz007. "getServerSideProps can only be exported from a page. You can’t export it from non-page files." is the key phrase of the link you shared. Thanks